# Changing row in dataset and updating database

Tags: c#, database, dataset, edit

I need to make an app which saves scores in database. Structure of database is NICK (`string`) which is primary key and PTS (`int`). If player has NICK, which already exists in database; points he got in last game should be add to PTS corresponding to NICK. I have trouble editing `DataSet` and then updating database.

I've tried to make it as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx) shows, but i don't have `FindBy(...)` method. I've spent 2 days searching the answer and couldn't get it.

Here is code I wrote:

```
private void dodajigrajbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nick = nicktextBox.Text;

    DataRow[] daneGracza = this.tFSDataSet.JIPP.Select("NICK = '" + nick + "'");
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("NICK", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("PTS", typeof(int));

    try
    {
        int temp;

        tFSDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        if (!daneGracza[0].IsNull("NICK")) { }
        temp = (int)daneGracza[0].ItemArray[1];
        table.Rows.Add(nick, temp+points);  // there are good values here

        // here should be code editing row in data set, but i had unheld 
        //exceptions when trying to do it like 
        //daneGracza[0].ItemArray[1] = table.Rows[0];

        this.jIPPTableAdapter.Update(tFSDataSet);

    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        this.jIPPTableAdapter.Insert(nick, points);
    }
    points = 0;
    this.jIPPTableAdapter.Fill(this.tFSDataSet.JIPP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but I can answer why you don't have FindByXXX() methods. They are generated by visual studio when you create typed datasets. More info you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):